# PHP regular expression - how to search for anything

Tags: php, string, expression, any

i.e. i have a string, which contains ANY,ANY kind of symbols,words, sentences:

```
<START>%6tge9ruj+_]`\Qe,3[][}~[wq]we-Oke|\;'"_p}|P{dl3=+fmwfoe-f <END>
```

how to:

```
1) get everything between <start> and <end>

2) replace everything <start> and <end>
```

thanks for answering!

Comment: What you need is an XML parser, not a regex.

Comment: I realize that you're using “start” and “end” as tags, but have you considered an XML parser?

Comment: @jack: doesn't look like xml, otherwise it'd be `<start></start>`. but otherwise, yeah... a DOM parser would be far more useful.

Comment: Have you tried `/<START>.*<END>/`?

Comment: @MarcB - You're correct. My apologies. But yes, a parser of some kind is what's called for here.

Answer (score 1):

Extracting the part between tags with regexp:

```
<?php

$text = '<START>%6tgruj+_]`\\Qe,3][}~[e-Oke|;\'"=+fmwfoe-aaa<END>aaaa<END>';
$pattern = '/<START>(.*?)<END>/';   //<-------- till the first occurence of <END>
$pattern = '/<START>(.*)<END>/';    //<-------- till the last occurence of <END>
$out = array();

preg_match($pattern, $text, $out);      var_dump($out);
?>
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/KWtP0w) But it's really not a job for regular expressions, you should think about using some parser.

Comment: If you _were_ to use something like this, and as mentioned above you're probably going to want a document parser instead, it'd be worth saying you'd probably want '.*?' as opposed to '.*', as if it's embedded in a wider document the regex engine's gunna be wasting a lot of time trying to maximise the match.

Comment: @jstephenson do you have an example of a document parser that parses `<something>xxx</somethingelse>`

Comment: @PeeHaa Whilst that doesn't alter the relevance of my comment in the main, <x> and <y> as delimiters in a stream which turns out not to be a pass at some XML-esque format would seem a peculiar thing to do, so a nudge in the direction of doc parsers is based upon a not-unreasonable widening of the scope.

Comment: Well considering everyone in here is shouting "use a parser" I would really like to at least see some example of such a parser everybody is talking about.